# Kerberos Single Sign On

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, kerberos

I am trying to implement Single Sign On using kerberos with ssh. I changed the below files and restarted the ssh daemon.

**/etc/ssh_config**

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

**/etc/sshd_config**

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

When I am trying to ssh from an ubuntu machine to centos. I got the below exception

```
Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm
```

But I am able to login without using password from centos machine to ubuntu. Kinit is working fine in both machines.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please add the log of the KDC during a login attempt and the relevant portion of `/var/log/secure' with `LogLevel DEBUG` on the server side.